# I am trying to hide jQuery tabs on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I am using this code for tabs it is working fine.

```
$('#banner div').hide(); 
$('.vert-menu li a').click(function(){
    $('.vert-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#banner div').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});
```

Now I am trying to hide div again when `mouseout` from `#banner div` and `.vert-menu li a`

I tried this code but it is not working.

```
('.vert-menu li a, #banner div').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.vert-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#banner div').hide();
});
```

here is the full code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TT3Qf/1/

Comment: Your HTML and a jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Have you used an alert to see if it's getting within the `mouseleave` function?

Comment: updated : http://jsfiddle.net/TT3Qf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/TT3Qf/3/

Working fine, you forgot $ sign in front of mouseleave function?

```
$('#banner div').hide();

$('.vert-menu li a').on('click',function () {
    $('.vert-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#banner div').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});

$('.vert-menu li a, #banner div').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.vert-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $('#banner div').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked i don't know why my code is not working even both are looking similar.

Comment: you forgot $ sign in front of mouseleave function :)